# Random shuffle using vector

Tags: c++, random, vector, shuffle

I am trying to generate non-repeated index (0-51) in an array and store some integers in it.
But the out-put seems weird. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand

// random generator function:
int myrandom (int i)
{
    return std::rand()%i;
}

int main ()
{

  int* temp = new int[52];

  std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=0; i<52; ++i) myvector.push_back(i);

  // using built-in random generator:
  std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );

  // using myrandom:
  std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myrandom);

  std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin();

  for(int i = 1;i<=24;i++)
  {
      temp[*it] = i;
      it++;

  }

  for(int i = 0;i<52;i++)
  {
      std::cout << temp[i];
      std::cout << '\n';
  }

  delete[]temp;
  temp = NULL;



  return 0;
}
```

What goes wrong here?

The out-put contains very huge number like : 1998373

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. But it still doesn't produce correct output.

Comment: Why are you setting only 24 elements of `temp`?

Comment: More to the point, why set only 24, but then try to print out all 52?

Comment: @CareyGregory because I need to let 24 elements randomly distribute in an array, and set the rest of index to be 1.

Comment: @14K : You are not setting remaining array to 1 in your code. Initialize `temp` with `std::fill(temp, temp+51, 1);` and then perform the `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new int[52]` returns uninitialized memory. You are only setting 24 of these values, the rest remains uninitialized. Maybe this:

```
for(int i = 1;i<=24;i++)
{
  temp[*it] = i;
  it++;
}
```

was meant to be

```
for(int i = 1;i<52;i++)
{
  temp[*it] = i;
  it++;
}
```

? Or set all values explicitly to `0` after the allocation.

Comment: I already tried this, it does work. But I don't want to fill out all of the index in an array.

Comment: @14K Then set the memory to `0`: `for (int i=0; i<52; ++i) temp[i]=0;` or something similar (put it right after you allocated `temp` with `new`).

Comment: @14K then you should initialize your `temp` something using `std::fill(temp, temp+51, 0);`

Comment: Well I think the question has to be, if you are only copying 24 elements to temp, what did you expect to see when you output 52 elements from temp, why did you allocate 52 elements in temp in the first place?

Comment: @john because I need to let 24 elements randomly distribute in an array(the index of array is 52), and set the rest of index to be 1.

Comment: @14K OK well setting the rest to 1 is the bit you didn't do. Daniel Frey's comment above shows one way to do that (except change `temp[i]=0;` to `temp[i]=1;`)

Comment: @john Because I was thinking the rest would be 0 if I didn't set the rest to 1. But the out-put contained very huge number like : 1998373. That's what I am confusing about.

Comment: @14K If you don't initialize a variable it's value will just be some garbage value, that's what you are seeing.

Comment: @john but Java doesn't :D. Is that because Java handled its own memory by using garbage collector?

Comment: @14K I don't think that's the reason. Java has a philosophy of defining behaviour for pretty much everything. C++ lets lots of things be implementation defined or just flat out undefined (like the actual value of an uninitialised variable). It's gets better efficiency like that but the cost is that it's hard to debug programs. In Java even bugged programs have well defined behaviour, in C++ they usually don't.

Comment: @14K : Have a look at Java Specification

Comment: @john I guess that's why people say I love Java but C++ is faster. Good explaination!